# Creating Relationship in MySQL error

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, mysql-error-1005

I have three tables (all InnoDB with primary keys having int(7) for type)

tblcustomers: primary key is customer_id

tblorders: primary key is order_id (has field for customer_id called order_customer)

tblorder_detail: primary key is order_detail_id (has field for order_id called order_id)

I want a to create a relationship so that deleting a customer deletes their order history.

I used the following statement to alter the Orders table:

```
ALTER TABLE `tblorders`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_myKey` FOREIGN KEY (`order_customer`) REFERENCES `tblcustomers` (`customer_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

This was successful and deleting a customer deletes their associated orders.

I then tried the following and I get an error:

```
ALTER TABLE `tblorder_detail`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_myKey` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `tblorders` (`order_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

This is the error (wtc-ecommerce is the name of the db):

1005 - Can't create table 'wtc-ecommerce.#sql-5d2_c2' (errno: 121)

Reading through other SO posts, seems like everything is correctly configured, so I'm lost.

Thanks

Comment: Check if it helps you to resolve http://verysimple.com/2006/10/22/mysql-error-number-1005-cant-create-table-mydbsql-328_45frm-errno-150/

Comment: Referencing #3 in your list, I changed the order_id value in the tblorder_details to order_id_value and that made no difference.  All my fields are unsigned.

Comment: Post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the 2 tables (`tblorders` and  `tblorder_detail`)

Comment: There are various ways this can appear. The 2 columns may not be the same exact type (INT UNSIGNED vs BIGINT SIGNED). Or tables not with InnoDB. Or not having Unique index on the referenced column.